# SharePoint 2010 using web service to insert a data that has a lookup into external BCS list

Tags: list, bcs

I've got a 2 SharePoint lists:

List A: This is an external list that's using Business Connectivity Services to connect to CRM. List B: This list contains a lookup field that linked into List A.

I am using the SharePoint web service: http://myserver/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx, to insert the data.

Problem: The value is inserted, however, it's not linked into BCS. (i.e. When I go to edit mode in the inserted list item, the field is blank).

Methods tried: I have tried using various fields in my List A, including the ID Field and other fields, but none works. I have also tried retrieving List A items using the web service, and use the value pattern (in this case: it's just the customer name in CRM), but it still doesnt work.

Possible cause of error: The value pattern of the BCS inserted is wrong.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1):

so we had to do teh same thing a little bit ago.

the final call is

```
            var entInst = BcsItem.GetEntityInstance(web.Site, "BEIM.BCS", "BeimBusinessUnit", prepop.BusinessUnit.Id.ToString());
            SPBusinessDataField dataField = threeyearlyFileItem.Fields["Business Unit"] as SPBusinessDataField;

            threeyearlyFileItem[dataField.RelatedField] = prepop.BusinessUnit.Id.ToString();

            BcsItem.SetSecondaryFields(threeyearlyFileItem, dataField, entInst);
```

You hvae to set teh field then set secondary fields

the class BcsItem does all teh hard work it is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel;
using Microsoft.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Collections;
using Microsoft.BusinessData.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.SharedService;

namespace BEIM.Webservices
{
    public class BcsItem
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// This hits the BCS and gets the instance basaed ont he key and the BCS details
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IEntityInstance GetEntityInstance(SPSite site, string nameSpace, string entityName, string key)
        {
            BdcService service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<BdcService>(String.Empty);
            SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
            IMetadataCatalog catalog = service.GetDatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog(serviceContext);
            IEntity entity = catalog.GetEntity(nameSpace, entityName);
            ILobSystemInstance LobSysteminstance = entity.GetLobSystem().GetLobSystemInstances()[0].Value;

            IEntityInstance iEInstance = null;
            Identity id = new Identity(key);

            //entity.GetIdentifiers();

            iEInstance = entity.FindSpecific(id, LobSysteminstance);
            return iEInstance;

        }

        /// <summary>  

        /// Set all secondary BCS fields for a given entity  
        /// </summary>  

        /// <param name="listItem">The item to set the fields for</param>  
        /// <param name="dataField">The BCS field itself</param>  
        /// <param name="entityInstance">The entity to get the values from</param>  

        public static void SetSecondaryFields(SPListItem listItem, SPBusinessDataField dataField, IEntityInstance entityInstance)
        {


            // Convert the entity to a formatted datatable  

            DataTable dtBDCData = entityInstance.EntityAsFormattedDataTable;

            // Set the BCS field itself (Display Value)  

            listItem[dataField.Id] = dtBDCData.Rows[0][dataField.BdcFieldName].ToString();

            // Get the specific finder method to get the columns that returns  
            IMethodInstance method = entityInstance.Entity.GetMethodInstances(MethodInstanceType.SpecificFinder)[0].Value;

            ITypeDescriptorCollection oDescriptors = method.GetReturnTypeDescriptor().GetChildTypeDescriptors()[0].GetChildTypeDescriptors();

            // Set the column names to the correct values  

            foreach (ITypeDescriptor oType in oDescriptors)
            {

                if (oType.ContainsLocalizedDisplayName())
                {

                    if (dtBDCData.Columns.Contains(oType.Name))
                    {

                        dtBDCData.Columns[oType.Name].ColumnName = oType.GetLocalizedDisplayName();

                    }

                }

            }

            // get the secondary field display names; these should be set  

            string[] sSecondaryFieldsDisplayNames = dataField.GetSecondaryFieldsNames();

            // loop through the fields and set each column to its value  

            foreach (string columnNameint in sSecondaryFieldsDisplayNames)
            {

                Guid gFieldID = listItem.Fields[String.Format("{0}: {1}", dataField.Title, columnNameint)].Id;

                listItem[gFieldID] = dtBDCData.Rows[0][columnNameint].ToString();

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some sort of same kind of problem. I have a List with lookup field which can hold up multiples. on the code I'm correctly populating the above said field, but it is not get reflected on the List.
Any suggestions ?